# No method found annotated with @Named#value

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I'm having trouble using MapStruct version 1.4.1 when I'm trying to implement my own mapping. This is code that I wrote:

```
package com.kucazdravlja.user.mappers;

import com.kucazdravlja.user.dto.NoticeBoardDto;
import com.kucazdravlja.user.entities.NoticeBoard;
import com.kucazdravlja.user.entities.NoticeBoardStatus;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.Named;

import java.util.Objects;

@Mapper(uses = {BaseJournalMapper.class})
public interface NoticeBoardMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "status", target = "status", qualifiedByName = "getNoticeBoardStatusName")
    NoticeBoard dtoToEntity(NoticeBoardDto noticeBoardDto);

    @Mapping(source = "status", target = "status", qualifiedByName = "getNoticeBoardStatusDescription")
    NoticeBoardDto entityToDto(NoticeBoard noticeBoard);

    @Named("getNoticeBoardStatusDescription")
    static String getNoticeBoardStatusDescriptionConverter(NoticeBoard noticeBoard) {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(NoticeBoardStatus.findByName(noticeBoard.getStatus())).getDescription();
    }

    @Named("getNoticeBoardStatusName")
    static String getNoticeBoardStatusNameConverter(NoticeBoardDto noticeBoardDto) {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(NoticeBoardStatus.findByName(noticeBoardDto.getStatus())).name();
    }
}
```

When running application it crashes and gives error

```
Error:(15, 5) java: Qualifier error. No method found annotated with @Named#value: [ getNoticeBoardStatusName ].
```

Not sure what is the problem because I have that method with that name.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your `@Mapping` annotation, you are telling mapstruct to use the field "status" as the source for the mapping. But the methods take `NoticeBoard` and `NoticeBoardDto` as parameters. You need to change the parameter type to whatever your `status` is. Assuming it is string:

```
@Named("getNoticeBoardStatusName")
default String getNoticeBoardStatusNameConverter(String status) {
    return Objects.requireNonNull(NoticeBoardStatus.findByName(status)).name();
}
```

Also, don't use static methods in mappers, use the `default` keyword instead.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, if you doesn't match the `@Context` variable type in your method, you will get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the `NoticeBoardDto` on that named function you can use that also:

```java
    @Mapping(source = ".", target = "status", qualifiedByName = "getNoticeBoardStatusName") // Set source to dot
    NoticeBoard dtoToEntity(NoticeBoardDto noticeBoardDto);


    @Named("getNoticeBoardStatusName")
    static String getNoticeBoardStatusNameConverter(NoticeBoardDto noticeBoardDto) {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(NoticeBoardStatus.findByName(noticeBoardDto.getStatus())).name();
    }
```